# Cancel an AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-timepicker

I´ve got a method that sets the time I want an alarm to fire. 
In this method I also got a Stop button that cancels the alarm

```
                    if(alarmManager != null){
                       alarmManager.cancel(pi);
                    }
```

My problem is that when I set the alarm, go out of the app and in again to cancel the alarm I get a nullPointer. Im guessing it is because the PendingIntent also closes when I leave the app (get set to null).

How can I prevent this from happening, so that I can cancel the alarm?

Heres the whole method:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setTime(){

    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() 
        {
            int callCount = 0;   //To track number of calls to onTimeSet()
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) 
            {
                 if(callCount == 1)    // On second call
                 {
                     String timeString = "";
                     timeString = selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute + ":00";
                     Log.d("TEST", "Chosen time : "+ timeString);
                     setAlarm(timePicker, selectedHour, selectedMinute);
                 }
                 callCount++;    // Incrementing call count.
            }
        }, hour, minute, true);
        mTimePicker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Set", mTimePicker);
        mTimePicker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Stop", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(alarmManager != null){
                    alarmManager.cancel(pi);
                }
            }
        });

        mTimePicker.setTitle(R.string.time);
        mTimePicker.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data that is used to construct your PendingIntent in a Bundle like shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

So when you open up your app again, you will be able to reconstruct the PendingIntent and cancel the alarm if needed.

EDIT: First of all you have to override `onSaveInstanceState` and save the data that is used to create your PendingIntent object like shown below:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the pending intent id
    savedInstanceState.putInt(PENDING_INTENT_ID, mPendingIntentId);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

After that, in your `onCreate` method you will check if the savedInstanceState is not null. If not null, restore the items from the savedInstanceState (Bundle) object like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mPendingIntentId = savedInstanceState.getInt(PENDING_INTENT_ID);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
        mPendingIntentId = YOUR_DEFAULT_INT_VALUE;
    }
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, mPendingIntentId, YOUR_INTENT, PendindIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

PendingIntent will be recreated every time you will enter your app, so you will be able to cancel the same alarm that has been triggered in a previous step.

EDIT 2 : Another approach in your case would be that since you have only one alarm, and it's id is always the same (which should be used for the PendingIntent's requestId), than you can simply recreate the PendingIntent whenever you want to add or cancel an alarm. A method like the one below would help you out.

```
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context){
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, YourBroadcastReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: This is just what i'm looking for. but how can i put the PendingIntent in the savedInstanceState.put..(...); I'm still a newbie when it comes to android

Comment: You don't need to put the PendingIntent itself in the Bundle, but the data which you used to construct it. Are there multiple alarms in your app?

Comment: No. theres only one alarm